# Status ERROR when trying to add() an OnDataPointListener

Tags: google-fit

I am trying to add a listener for raw data to a Sensor. I successfully discovered the BLE Sensor, I am even able to subscribe to it using the recording API but getting raw values via add() is not possible. The below code will print "Failed to register Listener" and the status is ERROR, with no resolution possible and no further explanation.

`findDataSources()` does return a Data Source of the appropriate type.

```
Fitness.SensorsApi.add(googleApiClient,
    new SensorRequest.Builder()
        .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_CYCLING_WHEEL_REVOLUTION)
        .setSamplingRate(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
        , new OnDataPointListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DataPoint: " + dataPoint.toString());
            }
         }).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
             @Override
             public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                 if (status.isSuccess()) {
                     Log.d(TAG, "Listener registered.");
                 } else {
                     Log.e(TAG, "Failed to register Listener.");
                     Log.e(TAG, status.toString());
                 }
         }
});
```

Comment: Which sensor is it? Some devices got other APIs than the normal one provided by google. For Example with Samsung you need to use other APIs and stuff.

Comment: The device is a DeskBike, it is correctly detected using the BleApi methods and i do not create DataSources manually.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `.setDataSource(dataSource)`  to your `SensorRequest:builder()` because the Device is optional but recommended in some cases because data sets can be specified. Also set the `samplingRate` a little bit higher - few sensors just support 5sec and more.

Comment: This seemed to be the problem. I now take the datasource all the way through the chain from discovery til registration and it works!

Comment: So I will write an answer because most users not reading commands - just looking for results.

Answer (score 0):

Some sensors are using other API (for example Samsung). So they need their own way to get access for some informations and bind it.

For this case you need to add `.setDataSource(dataSource)` to your `SensorRequest:builder()`. It´s optional but recommended in some cases, because the data sets can and need to be customized for usage.

Some sensors can´t provide the data in in to short intervals. In this case you need to set `samplingRate` higher that 5sec.